# How to convert this String to JSON?

Tags: powershell

So i have the following script that returns connection string of databases under server

```
Import-Module SqlServer

#SSAS 1103 
$oldAS = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$oldAS.connect("server1")

foreach ($db in $oldAS.Databases){
  #$dbName = $db.Name
  Write-Host $db.Name -Fore green
  $db.DataSources | ForEach-Object{$_.ConnectionString}
}


#SSAS 1200-1400 
$AS = new-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server
$AS.Connect("server1")

foreach ($dbt in $AS.Databases){
  $dbName = $dbt.Name
  $dbName
  $dbt.model.datasources[0].ConnectionString
}
```

the first connection/namespace is used for compatibility levels 1103
the 2nd connection/namespace `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server` is used for db's 1200-1400

however, we recently got databases that are 1400 but have a completely different format of connection string. the connection seems to be in JSON, even when looking at it from properties, compared to the traditional long connection string

i.e.

```
User Id=;Data Source=;Persist Security Info=True
```

VS

[image: json]

any databases with a data source of that format in the picture is not displaying back

I think its not displaying because the string is JSON format like in picture, not the regular string format like this:

```
User Id=;Data Source=;Persist Security Info=True
```

is there a way to convert the output to JSON? maybe that way it would be able to display?

[image: gm]

Comment: What does the output look like if you take the connection string and pipe it to `| ConvertTo-JSON`?

Comment: @trebleCode  it just added quotation marks at beginning and end of string. "User Id=;Data Source=;Persist Security Info=True" that was about it. it still didnt display for the other databases with JSON connect detail format. i am thinking it must be that the property is named ConnectionDetail and i am invoking ConnectionString instead...but i dont see any property like that as part of Tabular SSAS namespace

Comment: What members are available if you pipe `$dbt.model.datasources[0]` to `Get-Member`? Any other related string props?

Comment: @trebleCode editted my post and included picture of members

Comment: Would it be usable for you if you split the string on the semicolons and converted? `$a = 'User Id=;Data Source=;Persist Security Info=True'; $b = $a.split(';'); $json = $b | ConvertTo-JSON`

Comment: @trebleCode OMG i think i discovered something! so i decided to try using ToString() and it said cannot call method on null expression. this means that connection string is not returning anything for those kinda DB's! so i did this: $dbt.model.datasources[0].ToString() and it returned:  Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.StructuredDataSource! this is the typename used for this type of format!!!

Comment: Awesomesauce, hope that's a type you're able to work with and convert

Comment: @trebleCode how the heck is microsoft expecting us to know something like that exists? unbelieveable, what am i supposed to type in MSDOcs to ever find something like that?

Comment: They don't. Such is the debugging experience :) `Get-Member` is one of the most useful cmdlets in PowerShell

Comment: @trebleCode question; now since the databases are 1400 but each has different connection typename, how should i tell the for loop to output based on typename/property? how should i say if dbt has typename structured output structured connection, else connectionstring?

Comment: All powershell objects have a `GetType()` method, which you could call in your loop and use `if/else if/else` conditional operators based on the results

Comment: @trebleCode so i tried this: $dbt.model.datasources[0].ConnectionDetails and it only outputted this: Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ConnectionAddress

Comment: Does `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ConnectionAddress` have a `.ToString()` method you can use?

Comment: @trebleCode as soon as you posted i discovered that lol. $dbt.model.datasources[0].ConnectionDetails.ToString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is of typename Tabular StructuredDataSources

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.tabular.structureddatasource?view=analysisservices-dotnet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.tabular.connectiondetails?view=analysisservices-dotnet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.tabular.credential?view=analysisservices-dotnet

Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ConnectionAddress has a .ToString() and even tojson()

```
$dbt.model.datasources[0].ConnectionDetails.ToString()
$dbt.model.datasources[0].Credential.ToString()
```